# Giving ID to dynamically created button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a set of buttons using jQuery and give them id's, but when I try to reference their id's later, it doesn't seem to work. What can I do to it to fix it?

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
    $("h2")
    .append('<input type="button" value="Display Answer">')
    .button()
    .attr("id", i);
};


$("button").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") === "all") {
        for(i=0;i<answerArr.length+1;i++){
            $("#p" + i).text(answerArr[i-1]);
        }
    } else {
        $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).text(answerArr[$(this).attr("id")-1]);
    }  
});
```

Comment: `.append()` returns the element it was called on, not the newly appended element.

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` returns the element it was called on, not the newly appended element.  So you are adding the ID (and also calling `.button()`) on the `<h2>` element(s).

Try using `.appendTo()` instead, and also adding the ID when you create the element:

```
$('<input/>', {
    type: 'button',
    id: i,
    value: 'Display Answer'
}).appendTo('h2').button();
```

Answer (score 0):

you're setting the `h2` id.  do this instead:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
 $("h2")
   .append('<input type="button" id="' + i + '" value="Display Answer">').button();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably looking for the `<button></button>` element, not `<input/>`.  Next, html and javascript tend to lose their minds when referencing IDs of elements that begin with an integer.  So here is my version of what you are trying to do:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
  $("h2")
      .append(
               $("<button/>", {'id':'_'+i).text("Display Answer") 
             )
      .button();
}
```

Comment: HTML5 lets you use IDs that start with numbers :-)

Comment: Very true, I sometimes live in the past :/

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++) {
$("h2")
.append('<input type="button" value="Display Answer" id="'+i+'">')
};
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/PbEnC/

Answer (score 0):

If you want the handler to be invoked on every button, you need to change your selector when wiring the event handler. Instead of **button** use **[type=button]**

```
$("[type=button]").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") === "all") {
        for(i=0;i<answerArr.length+1;i++){
            $("#p" + i).text(answerArr[i-1]);
        }
    } else {
        $("#p" + $(this).attr("id")).text(answerArr[$(this).attr("id")-1]);
    }  
});
```

Also, you can set button id, right in the append.